# Drush make on Windows 7: Where does my ssh key go?

Tags: drush

I'm on windows 7 using (I think) the current version of drush, installed using the msi install file.

I have to download a proprietary drupal distro from a proprietary server using a drush make file containing ssh directives.

I've registered my ssh key on the server side already.

I cannot figure out where to put my ssh key on my client side. I've been scouring google and the drupal forums and gotten no certainty about what to do.

I saw one item about setting an option in a file called drushrc.php. But I don't see one in my current install. Neither do I know how to construct one or where to put it.

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Thanks for reading.